# T-SQL query to check if given set of data is available are not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table and my java application is sending a list of descriptions.

Now I need to verify if all the description are available in the table or not, if all the description is not available in the table then an error has to be raised with the missing description.

For example: Java application is sending message as 'tree', 'flower', 'plant'.

In SQL Server, there is a column `description` - I need to check if 'tree', 'flower', 'plant' are available or not.

If anyone is unavailable like 'plant' is not there in the table then raise an error that 'plant' is unavailable.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: How (in what form) is the data passed to the database? And where should the error raise (where is the check taking place), on the database or in the application?

Comment: In my  java application i have made a DB connection, so i am framing the query in JAVA application.The error needs to be raise in DB so that Java application can catch that error and proceed further.

Comment: Does _is available_ means it is **present** in the table?

Comment: Yes @SalmanA the table contains all the descriptions, java application is passing some sets of description and the table needs to raise an error if it is unable to find data which is passed by the java application

Answer (score 1):

You can try to left join the table to the descriptions. If there is no match in the table, the columns from that table remain `NULL`, so you can filter only for `NULL`s. Like that you have a list of descriptions, that don't exist.

```
SELECT i.description
       FROM (SELECT 'tree'
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'flower'
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'plant') i
            LEFT JOIN elbat t
                      ON t.description = i.description
       WHERE t.description IS NULL;
```

Comment: My apologise but i am not well versed with SQL so could you please frame the query. My table name is say 'test' and column name is 'description'. So in this query i am unable to get the references for 'i' and 't'.Could you please help me with this

Comment: I have only one table where i need to check so i am not sure if the reference 'i' and 't' will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

u meant somethin like this?

```
if not exists (select 1 from table1 where description='plant')
begin
    RAISERROR('your custom error',16,1)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but in this query we are just checking for 'plant', my requirement is to check for all the rows like 'tree', 'flower','plant'.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitToItems] (
    @pString NVARCHAR(3999), --!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES
    @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS @Items TABLE (ItemNumber INT, Item NVARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    IF Replace(@pString, '''', '') = ''
        SET @pString = '';
    WITH E1 (N)
    AS (
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
        ), E2 (N)
    AS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM E1 a, E1 b
        ), E4 (N)
    AS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM E2 a, E2 b
        ), cteTally (N)
    AS (
        SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString), 0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY (
                        SELECT NULL
                        )
                )
        FROM E4
        ), cteStart (N1)
    AS (
        SELECT 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t.N + 1
        FROM cteTally t
        WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
        ), cteLen (N1, L1)
    AS (
        SELECT s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1), 0) - s.N1, 8000)
        FROM cteStart s
        )
    INSERT INTO @Items
    SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY l.N1
            ), Item = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1), 1, 100)
    FROM cteLen l
    RETURN
END
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SplitToItems('''tree'',''flower'',''plant''', ',')
```